# (C Programming) How do I use a data structure and function which are defined in another file?

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, hashmap, include

Say, I have a file `dataStructure.c` and `dataStructure.h`. (My data structure is a hash map.) These files contain the implementation of the data structure and methods for adding new entries to the structure as well as retrieving entries.

Here's an example:

```
// dataStructure.h

struct node {
    char *label;
    int address;
    struct node *next; // Points to the next node.
};

struct ourTable {
    int size;
    struct node **list; // List of all the (key, value) pairs.
};

// Then, here are methods to create table, add new entries and retrieving them.
struct ourTable createTable(int size);

void addEntry(struct ourTable *t, char *label, int address);

unsigned retrieveAddress(struct ourTable* table, char *label);
```

The function `retrieveAddress` basically just returns the address of that label. Since I am trying to implement a hash map, which is just a data structure of several (key, value) pairs. In my case, the key is `label` whereas value is `address`.

```
unsigned retrieveAddress( struct ourTable* table, char *label)
{
    int bin = 0;
    bin = hashFunction(table, label); // Hashing function

    struct node *list = table->list[bin];
    struct node *entryItem = list;
    while(entryItem)
    {
        if (entryItem->label == label)
        {
            return entryItem->address; // Returns the address of that label.
        }
        entryItem = entryItem->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Then, I have another file, `establishTable.c` which just uses the methods implemented in `dataStructure.h` to create a table and then add new entries. This is what I wrote in that file:

```
// establishTable.c

#include "dataStructure.h"

struct ourTable establishTable()
{    
    struct ourTable table = createTable(1000); // Create a table with a maximum of 1000 entries.
    addEntry(&table, "word", 1234);
}
```

And what I want to do is to pass the structure `ourTable` with the new entries I inserted in `establishTable.c` to the main file `main.c`. To illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
// main.c

#include "dataStructure.h"

#include "establishTable.h"

int main()
{
    // I'm not sure how to pass the data structure... Something like this:
    struct ourTable table = establishTable(); 

    // Get the retrieveLabel function from dataStructure.h and use it here.
    printf("retrieved from the table at %u\n\n", retrieveAddress(&table,"word") );
}
```

I tried running the `main.c`. It doesn't show any errors but it just outputs

```
retrieved from the table at 0
```

which just tells me that the table I already established was not passed on at all. The output should be 1234.

So, how do I pass a data structure and the result of a function from another file to my `main.c` file? It works when I just do everything in `establishTable.c` but that is not my intention. I have tried the `extern` method as suggested in other threads, but nothing works.

Comment: You should enable all compiler warnings. And listen to them. The compiler should complain about `establishTable` not returning anything.

Comment: Without knowing what `retrieveLabel` is supposed to return, we cannot tell if or what is wrong. With "word" being the only entry, position 0 seems not so bad after all. What output did you expect?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry about that, I will make some edits. It should output 1234, not 0.

Comment: What is `hashFunction`?  What is `addEntry`? `retrieveAddress` returns an `unsigned int`, but it should return a `struct node *`. `establishTable` doesn't return anything.Hint: compile with all warnings enables and pretend the warnings are errors.

Comment: `entryItem->label == label` should probably be `strcmp(entryItem->label, label)==0`. The `address` field of node is an int, `retrieveAddress` returns an unsigned. There is no way for retrieveAddress to signal that the key is not present (excepted if there is an invalid value).

Comment: You're thinking that your problem is that those functions are in separate files. I can guarantee that it's not: if you put everything into `main.c` (yes, it's possible), it still won't work. If it *happens* to work then, it'll merely mean that you're lucky that time - the bug will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement

```
struct ourTable establishTable()
{    
    struct ourTable table = createTable(1000); // Create a table with a maximum of 1000 entries.
    addEntry(&table, "word", 1234);
    return table;
}
```